# if just data value automatically is changing, how copy each of data values to paste into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

how do you offer yore logic to me
and this is example.
    The data is being uploaded into my excel in pay something like that
        cells(1,1) = 200 cell(1,2) = alpa
        cells(2,1) = 250 cell(2,2) = veta
        cells(i,1) = ___ cell(i,2) = _____
        ...............................

Comment: May use Worksheet_Calculate event with  use of global variable for comparing with previous value to detect change.

Comment: nice idea but I can't how to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try something like following

```
Public Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Ws
    'May use loop or Directly assigned  to array if range is large
    Var1 = .Range("B2").Value
    Var2 = .Range("C2").Value
    Var3 = .Range("D2").Value
    Var4 = .Range("E2").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

and at `Sheet1` Calculate event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Cvar1, Cvar2, Cvar3, Cvar4
Dim LastRow As Long


    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ColNo As Long, ColLR As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With


    With Ws1
    Cvar1 = .Range("B2").Value
    Cvar2 = .Range("C2").Value
    Cvar3 = .Range("D2").Value
    Cvar4 = .Range("E2").Value
    End With

    If Cvar1 <> Var1 Or Cvar2 <> Var2 Or Cvar3 <> Var3 Or Cvar4 <> Var4 Then
        With Ws2
        LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Cvar1
        .Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Cvar2
        .Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Cvar3
        .Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Cvar4
        .Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Now    ' Used to log time in column A. May delete this line if not required

        Var1 = Cvar1
        Var2 = Cvar2
        Var3 = Cvar3
        Var4 = Cvar4
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

modify the code to your requirement

Comment: You made my day